# Update List of entities in one query jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to update a list of objects in one query.
I have class Parent which has a list of Child in ManyToMany relation.
I need to update a list of Parent by setting children list to empty(remove all children references from join table).
Currently i'm setting children list to empty and updating each entity in a query with a merge action,but when i have a large list of pharmacies there are too many queries.

i tried this query:

> `update Parent p set p.children=:children where p in (:parents)`

where :children is a `new HashSet<Child>`

but it gives me error

> unexpected end of subtree

Is there any way to update a list in one query ? I'm using jpa entity manager.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you miss `where` keyword

```
update Parent p set p.children=:childrenwhere where p in (:parents)
```

or you can try with id

```
update Parent p set p.children=:childrenwhere where p.id in (:parentIds)
```

Comment: thanks,but i have `where` in hql string... there was a mistake in my post

Comment: Try also without brackets p in :parents